# I can't get the className property to work on Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, classname

I tried this javascript function before adding `a.className = "year";` and everything worked properly, but then, adding it, I couldn't get the page to load neither with Safari nor Google Chrome. What I need to do is just add a class to the new `a` element, I tried also with `a.setAttribute("class", "year");` but I got the same error: the page wouldn't load.. If someone knew how to help me I would be very grateful!

```
function create_timeline() {

    timeline = document.getElementById("timeline_ul");
    years = document.getElementsByClassName("year");
    for (i=0;i<years.length;i++) {
        if (years.item(i).nodeType==1) {
            year = years.item(i).innerHTML;
            a = document.createElement("a");
            a.innerHTML = year;
            a.className = "year";
            timeline.appendChild(a);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note as an aside: You are creating an `<a>` tag, but not setting the href property to make the link tag actually do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

> but I got the same error: the page wouldn't load..

the problem is, your code runs in a infinite loop. The reason for that is:

1. With the call below you've fetched all elements with class "year". The collection that is returned is **a dynamic collection**

   ```
   years = document.getElementsByClassName("year");
   ```
2. while iterating through the collection, you are creating new anchor elements, and setting them the "year" class.
3. When you append them to the document, they will be automagically added to the collection created 1st step, because it is a dynamic collection, because new elements match the "subject" (here the class "year") of the collection.

to avoid infinite loops, you have many possibilities.

1. cache the length property in a variable

   ```
   var i=0, len = years.length;i<len;i++
   ```

but with this approach, you cannot be sure whether new elements are appended to the collection or added in some "logical" or "random" order.

1. Convert the collection to a JavaScript array

   ```
   years = document.getElementsByClassName("year");
   years = Array.prototype.slice.call(years, 0);
   ```
2. or use document.querySelectorAll, which returns a **static** collection of elements.

   ```
   years = document.querySelectorAll('.year');
   ```

I would go for approach #2 or #3.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.. I needed the "year" class to apply a style to the new "a" elements but since I don't necessarily need that they'd be added to the dynamic collection I'll just change the class value and I guess it should work. Thank you very much, I think without your help I would have been stuck on that point for quite a lot :D